# Container platform that shuts down container after execution of program

Tags: web-apps, software-development, web-development, node.js, web-services

Is there any service which allows me to spawn temporary containers on the go, to run a UNIX executable, and then shut down the container as soon as the execution ends?

I’m looking for a budget friendly solution.

## Context

I am building an online programming competition judge, to run and compile code using docker containers.

I want to isolate each code submission and hence would run them in isolated containers for security reasons and for limiting resources (spawn a new container on request and destroy it after compiling and running the test code).

Comment: You don't have your own server(s), right?

Comment: If I understand correctly, any service where you can spawn a new container based on a particular specification, use it, then shut it down, is OK? There are many companies that provide this service, for various prices.

Comment: Is "serverless" what you are looking for?

Comment: Please clarify then ask us to reopen, thanks :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes, I don't own any servers. I'm looking at either GCP or AWS to host my servers as the last option. To clarify my use case, I would need mulitple containers to be spawned to run multiple submissions concurrently, and kill/remove them after ther task is done. Can you please specify which companies provide this service?

Comment: @Thomas, I'm not really sure. We're looking at an affordable solution which satifies our use case.

Comment: Is the "task" a single UNIX process that you run and that dies when the task is finished? For instance a single UNIX shell script that pulls the source code, builds, and runs the program in a synchronous manner.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yes it is like a single UNIX process.My dockerfile image is linux image with compilers for multiple languages installed, for each code submission I compile and run the code in a container and return the ouput, the container dies after executing the code.

Comment: I rewording your question and reopened it. Could you please check that it still conveys your requirements? By the way, please be more specific about the submissions: What programming language? Do they need specific OS features such as network access or GPU, or installed software such as a database engine or various libraries?

Comment: I guess that I misunderstand, but why not have the container run your program, then `sudo shutdown -h now` ?